# How to use ng-repeat in a slider using Ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, slide

I am using ng-repeat to show data in different slides in a slidebox. Instead of getting a slidebox with three different slides, I get three slideboxes vertically. 
I have tried moving the `ng-repeat="prize in event.prizes"` lower in the DOM but still does not work.

Is there any other way to get one slidebox with different slides containing the data from ng-repeat ?

```
<ion-slide-box ng-repeat="prize in event.prizes">
  <ion-slide>
     <div class="item item-thumbnail-left">
     <h4 class=" pull-right">{{prize.name}}</h4>
     <p class="pull-right" ng-bind-html="prize.description"></p>
       </div>
  </ion-slide>
```

Comment: how did you solve it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently your `ng-repeat` applies to the slide**box** instead of the slides itself. Move the `ng-repeat` to the `<ion-slide>` element:

```
<ion-slide-box>
    <ion-slide ng-repeat="prize in event.prizes">
        <div class="item item-thumbnail-left">
            <h4 class=" pull-right">{{prize.name}}</h4>
            <p class="pull-right" ng-bind-html="prize.description"></p>
       </div>
    </ion-slide>
</ion-slide-box>
```

Seems to work: http://jsfiddle.net/tt4w76sg/2/

Comment: When I move it like this: <ion-slide ng-repeat="prize in event.prizes">  
I get all data in one slide .

Comment: Yes I see. I had another prb that cause my prb. Thank you

Comment: How can i add titles in header with left/right navigation buttons also, so that to change the slide with navigation buttons in header.